# Silverlight AccentColor Theme Issues

Tags: vb.net, silverlight

I am trying to build a Business Application using the AccentColor Theme by copy/pasting the styles into the asset folder and adding the Merged Dictionaries in the app.xaml. After getting everything in place, per the instructions, I get 100+ errors about controls that do not exist like the buttonspinner. I currently have the Silverlight 4 toolkit installed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the control isn't used in your solution, you'll get errors. You have 2 options:

-Comment out the styles for the controls you're not using.

-Create a page that has all the controls specified in the styles that you think you’ll use, and comment out the styles for the controls you're not using.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I think I will just build out for the controls I am using because there are a lot that I am not. :) Thanks!